# Powershell: Can we change Write-Progress UI?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

Is it possible to change Write-Progress color scheme and other UI things, like progress bar?

Presently, its light green with a progress bar composed of "O"... And I want to change the color (or remove the color) and replace that "O" with something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the foreground and background colors of the `Write-Progress` output by modifying the `ProgressForegroundColor` and `ProgressBackgroundColor` of the [`$host.privatedata`](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/06/06/color-my-powershell-world.aspx) `ConsoleColorProxy` object.

For example, if you really hate your eyes:

```
$host.privatedata.ProgressForegroundColor = "darkgreen";
$host.privatedata.ProgressBackgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm. I was just able to match the background color of Progress bar with the background color of Console using:

"$Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor=$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor"

Comment: Only thing left is the change the Progress Showing character i.e. "O".

Do you know how can we do that?

Comment: Not that I've found. If my answer resolved (most) of your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This would not help in PowerShell ISE `Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE)`. There changing color is not supported I think.

Answer (score 4):

The letter "o" is hardcoded within the class Microsoft.PowerShell.ProgressNode, in the method RenderFull. The class is in the Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost assembly.

If you really want to change the "o" you could write your own host. I have seen several questions about custom hosts on SO and MS has it documented on the MSDN website.